# Unable to deploy a CNN model on GCP AI platform

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to deploy a model to GCP AI Platform but not getting anywhere, I know similar question has been asked before, but I can't make out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. I'm using jupyter notebook for development.

```
MODEL_NAME='CLASSIFIER' 
VERSION_NAME='v1' 
RUNTIME_VERSION='1.13' 
REGION='europe-west1'

!gcloud ai-platform models create {MODEL_NAME} --regions {REGION}
```

The model is created in the global end point

```
!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} \
--model {MODEL_NAME} \
--origin gs://{BUCKET}/{MODEL_DIR} \
--python-version 3.7 \
--runtime-version {RUNTIME_VERSION} \
--package-uris gs://{BUCKET}/{PACKAGES_DIR}/sentiment_classifier-0.1.tar.gz \
--prediction-class=model_prediction.CustomPrediction \
--machine-type mls1-c4-m4
```

but when I try to create the version, it tries to create it in the regional end point and fails, or so I think

*Using endpoint [https://us-central1-ml.googleapis.com/]
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Machine type is not available on this endpoint.*

[image]

Comment: I think mls1-c4-m4 is available in alpha and not in beta

Comment: `Using endpoint [https://us-central1-ml.googleapis.com/]` the endpoint seems in the US and you have a model in europe. Because the mls1-c4-m4 is a legacy and beta machine type, it could be only available in use-cetnral1 and not in europe. Try with a model in us, or with another machine type

Comment: I couldn't find the machine type in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction) I agree with guillaume, you should try creating the model in the same region ( defaults us ) and using the official machine types available.

Comment: I did try creating the model and version in the us-central1 region and with a different machine type as well as per the documentation, but sadly no luck.

Comment: using the GCP UI, under `ai platform->models->version` do you have a model created and also do you have an existing model_dir with model info in you storage?. Also, Are you following a tutorial?? if so, can you provide the link of it.

Comment: Also, when you create the model, you have to specify the region for both `!gcloud ai-platform models create {MODEL_NAME} --region {REGION}` and `!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} \
--model {MODEL_NAME} \  --region {REGION} ...` please make sure both shares the same region.

Comment: @Betjens 
1. Yes, The model is already created and i do have an dir with model and pre-processing class stored, the tutorial --> https://towardsdatascience.com/game-of-thrones-twitter-sentiment-with-keras-apache-beam-bigquery-and-pubsub-382a770f6583
2. Yes I did specify the --region flag for both model and version creation

Comment: I dont know if this its because of the support of the beta command but i try using `! gcloud ai-platform models create $MODEL_NAME \  --region global` and then remove the `--region`  when executing `gcloud beta ai-platform versions create` and it worked ( both the model and the version create will point to endpoint `https://ml.googleapis.com/` )

Comment: were you able to get your commands (for model and versions) to point `https://ml.googleapis.com/ ` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the command without issues. For it I use an existing [sample](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/scikit-learn/custom-pipeline.ipynb?hl=cs) to replicate the execution of the commands .

As a remark, both models point to `https://ml.googleapis.com` as this region accepts the execution of beta commands as the one used for this case. You can see details of it on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ai-platform/versions/create) under `--region`. As a note, you can choose different main regions but keep in mind that it should support the execution of beta commands and that both (the model and the version) points to the same [endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/regions).

**model**

```
MODEL_NAME = 'CensusPredictor'
VERSION_NAME = 'v1'
REGION = "global"  

! gcloud ai-platform models create $MODEL_NAME \
  --regions $REGION
```

output

```
WARNING: To specify a region where the model will deployed on the global endpoint, please use `--regions` and do not specify `--region`. Using [us-central1] by default on https://ml.googleapis.com. Please note that your model will be inaccessible from https://us-central1-ml.googelapis.com
Learn more about regional endpoints and see a list of available regions: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/regional-endpoints

Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
Created ai platform model [projects/<my-project-id>/models/CensusPredictor].
```

**beta ai-platform versions create**

```
! gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME --model $MODEL_NAME \
  --origin gs://$BUCKET_NAME/custom_pipeline_tutorial/model/ \
  --runtime-version 1.13 \
  --python-version 3.5 \
  --framework SCIKIT_LEARN \
  --package-uris gs://$BUCKET_NAME/custom_pipeline_tutorial/code/census_package-1.0.tar.gz \
  --region $REGION \
  --machine-type mls1-c1-m2
```

output

```
Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......done.
```

Comment: Hello J1ten, have you managed to make it work?